# $scope not working within function AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My Code :

HTML

`<body ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller="loginCtrl" >
    <div class="loginWrap"  >
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username " ng-model="user" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password " ng-model="pass" />
    <input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="checkLogin()" />
    <span ng-bind="resultLog"></span>
</div>
</body>`

Angular Code :::

```
 var appLog = angular.module('loginApp',[])
 .controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$http){

 $scope.checkLogin = function(){

  if($scope.user.length > 0 && $scope.name.length > 0  )
  {
      $http.post('php/checkLogin.php',{'n':$scope.user, 'p':$scope.pass})
         .success(function(data)
         {
            if(data)
            {
                $scope.resultLog = "Valid"
            }
             else
            {
                $scope.resultLog = "InValid"
            }
         })
         .error(function()
         {
           $scope.resultLog="Error"
         })
  }
  else
  {
    $scope.resultLog = "Fill All Fields";
  } // end of validation


 } })
```

---

I am learning  angular JS.. and execute some..

Problem :: `$scope.resultLog` Not working

Scope Obejct not working inside the function..
it is declare in LoginCtrl and
i m using inside the function, declare inside the LoginCtrl

Thanks in advance

Comment: check my answer .....its working only thing you have to initialize `user` and `name` other wise it will be `undefined` so you cannot check the length of undefined

Comment: @Mik378 ... may be its $scope.pass.. i wrote wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have to initialize `user` and `name` other wise it will be **undefined** so you cannot check the length of **undefined**

Try this one

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/4002/)

```
var appLog = angular.module('loginApp',[]);

appLog.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$http){
$scope.user="";
$scope.pass="";
$scope.checkLogin = function(){

if($scope.user.length > 0 && $scope.pass.length > 0  )
{
      $http.post('php/checkLogin.php',{'n':$scope.user, 'p':$scope.pass})
         .success(function(data)
         {
            if(data)
            {
                $scope.resultLog = "Valid"
            }
             else
            {
                $scope.resultLog = "InValid"
            }
         })
         .error(function()
         {
           $scope.resultLog="Error"
         })
}
else
{
  $scope.resultLog = "Fill All Fields";
} // end of validation

} });
```

Comment: What is the point to have `$scope.user` and `$scope.name` separately? Makes no sense to me

Comment: But user and pass are strictly related, it composes credentials. I'd prefer have it in the same scope variable like `$scope.credentials.name`, `$scope.credentials.pass`. Indeed you are in a "Login" controller.

Answer (score 2):

**In your controller, you use `$scope.name`, what does it point to?** since you have `ng-model="user"`, not `ng-model="name"`.

Your input doesn't point to `user.name` directly but to `user`. You want to change it like that:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username " ng-model="user.name" />
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.checkLogin = function(){

  $scope.user = {};    

  if($scope.user.name.length > 0 && $scope.user.name.length > 0  )

  //......

}
```

Comment: @Mik378 +1 for you answer